# Creating an edit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to create a modal to pop up when any cell from E:3 too E:40 is edited on google sheets as "TRUE" as I would need to add information to another table. But no matter what I do it wont trigger when I edit E3, any thoughts on how to make the edit work on app scirpt?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Advances" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart == 3 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    trigger()
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  I put a checkbox in E3

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart == 3 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1")
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Hi ")
  }
}
```